# How to find the base number of of two number systems when there's a difference in the quanity of numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-systems, cryptarithm

The problem is as follows:

> In two numbering systems which are of consecutive bases, there are
> about $120$ three-digit numerals more than the other. Find the
> smallest of these bases.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{base 11}\\
2.&\textrm{base 13}\\
3.&\textrm{base 9}\\
4.&\textrm{base 15}\\
5.&\textrm{base 14}\\
\end{array}$

This problem makes me confused. How exactly should it be assessed?. I'm assuming that the author of this problem intends to say that there are two numbers as follows:

$\overline{abc}_{(\alpha)}$ and $\overline{cde}_{(\beta)}$

Then I believe it mentions that there is a difference between $120$ numbers between these digits. Therefore in order to avoid falling into the [telephone post error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error) then I think it meant:

$\overline{abc}_{(\alpha)}-\overline{cde}_{(\beta)}=120-1=119$

This assumes that the first number is greater than the second.

But here's the catch, **as it stands there are too many variables to guess** or poinpoint where to start any sort of inspection which makes the problem to be a guessing game.

Can someone help me with an **approapiate method and a step by step approach** on how to solve this problem?. It would help me a lot that the answer would be an easy to understand approach.

Answer (score 1):

We have base $b$ and base $b+1$. In base $b$, there are $b^3-b^2$ three-digit numbers. Likewise, in base $b+1$ there are $(b+1)^3-(b+1)^2$, so this count exceeds that for base $b$ by
$$(b+1)^3-(b+1)^2-b^3+b^2= 3b^2+b $$
and this is given to be "about 120". If we ignore the $b$, this means that $3b^2\approx 120$, so $b^2\approx 40 $, and $b$ should be $6$ or $7$. With $b=6$, $3b^2+b=114$, and with $b=7$, $3b^2+b=154$. So it seems that $b=6$ was intended.

Comment: Howdy! Upon looking in my book the official answer is 13. I don't know how did they got there. What could be wrong?. Perhaps can you explain me?. Is it that there is a typo or maybe something not considered in your solution?. Are we taking into account the fencepost error?. There's an identity you mentioned about the bases $b^{3}-b^{2}$ to be the 3-digit numerals. Can you include a reference for this?. Again, if such is held true, then the rest seems logical but I don't get very well how did they got to the answer?. **Can you please attend these questions?**